# jQuery Validate not working with CSS selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am testing jQuery Validate plugin but I am facing some issues when trying to validate the controls. I am not trying to use any FORM element in the page. I am trying to use css selector to get the elements and add some custom rules to it.

Here is my code

```
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.custom').validate({
                rules: {
                    name: 'required',
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    name: "Please specify your name",
                    email: {
                        required: "We need your email address to contact you",
                        email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        function valid() {
            return $('.custom').valid();
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .error { color: Red; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" method="get" action="">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="custom" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="email" class="custom" /><br />
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return valid();" />
    </form>
</body>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Can someone point it out? Is this not allowed in jQuery.Validate? Is a FORM element a MUST for the validate to work?

PS: If I use #form (`$('#form').validate({`) as the selector it works totally fine.

Thanks
Senthil S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is a FORM element a MUST for the validate to work?
>
> PS: If I use `#form` `($('#form').validate({)` as the selector it works
>   totally fine.

YES, you already answered your own question.

The `.validate()` function can **only** be initialized on a `<form>` element.

```
$('#yourform').validate({ ... })
```

---

Also, you do **not** need a `onclick="return valid();"` inside the `submit` button.  Nor will you need a function called `valid()` to check the form.  It's all superfluous.

The plugin already captures the `submit` event and checks the form automatically.

**See:  http://jsfiddle.net/XGLYt/**

---

**Quote OP's Title:**

> jQuery Validate not working with CSS selector

Yes it is.  `#form` is a perfectly valid "CSS selector" and it works.

As explained above, your "target" must be the `<form>` element.

Comment: This is just testing. But in my main application, the validation will be dynamic (the controls to validate will change dynamically based on user action). I would like to know whether css selector validation will work or not.

Comment: @SenthilS, your terminology is mixed up a bit.  Yes, you can use a CSS selector, after all `#form` **is** a CSS selector.  But **no**, you cannot "target" anything except the `<form>` and I've already answered that.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I guess my main application is complex to use validate with minimal configuration. I need to manipulate it or trick it to my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the `<form>` id `#form` selector instead of class assigned to inputs:

```
$('#form').validate({
```

Comment: Your wording is as convoluted as the OP's.  Did you mean to say, "`id` selector instead of `class` selector"?  That makes no difference as long as the `<form>` is targeted.  Or did you mean to say, "`<form>` element instead of `<input>` element"?